# What are the restrictions of solana rpc and websocket?

Tags: solana

I use solana-go https://github.com/gagliardetto/solana-go
When I request SendAndConfirmTransaction 100 times concurrently, an error will be reported.

```
    _, err = confirm.SendAndConfirmTransaction(
      context.TODO(),
      this.getRpcClient(),
      this.wsClient,
      tx,
    )
    if err != nil {
      panic(err)
    }
```

and error:

```
panic: (*jsonrpc.RPCError)(0x140001a1800)({
 Code: (int) 429,
 Message: (string) (len=83) "Connection rate limits exceeded, contact your app developer or support@rpcpool.com.",
 Data: (interface {}) <nil>
})
```

**Connection rate limits exceeded, contact your app developer or support@rpcpool.com.**

When I reduce to 50 concurrent, there is no problem, But I can't ask again 50 times, otherwise I will report an error.

I want to know **What are the restrictions of solana rpc and websocket? and whether there is any way to increase the number of concurrency.**

Answer (score 1):

Here are the limits if you are using Solana Labs RPC (i.e. devnet, testnet, mainnet):
https://docs.solana.com/cluster/rpc-endpoints

If you were to host or use a another RPC provider, their rates may vary and allow (maybe at a cost) higher rates.